# How can I set a cookie with expire time?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am setting a cookie with JavaScript and it is working fine but it is not taking the expire time I am giving. It keeps on taking session value regardless of what I give, below is the code which I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794989/how-to-set-a-cookie-to-expire-in-1-hour-in-javascript)

```
var now = new Date();
var time = now.getTime();
var expireTime = time + 1000*60;
now.setTime(expireTime);
var tempExp = 'Wed, 31 Oct 2012 08:50:17 GMT';
document.cookie = aaa+'='+sStr+';expires='+now.toGMTString()+';path=/';
```

I tried giving hard-coded value but still it is showing expire as session in chrome dev tool

```
var tempExp = 'Wed, 31 Oct 2012 08:50:17 GMT';
document.cookie = aaa+'='+sStr+';expires='+tempExp+';path=/';
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: how are you checking the time of expiration of your cookie?

Comment: polin: in chrome press F12 (alternatively go to tools-> developer tools). It will open the frame below, there you can check.

Comment: I know how it comes. My question is can you see the expiration time. I've tried console.log(document.cookie) but there you can see the cookie not the expiration time

Comment: Yes in 'Expires' column(after path column) it shows the date and time when the cookie will expire. But in my case it shows 'session' which means it will expire when I close the browser

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I've set the time to 1000*36000.

```
function display() { 
  var now = new Date();
  var time = now.getTime();
  var expireTime = time + 1000*36000;
  now.setTime(expireTime);
  document.cookie = 'cookie=ok;expires='+now.toUTCString()+';path=/';
  //console.log(document.cookie);  // 'Wed, 31 Oct 2012 08:50:17 UTC'
}
```

[image: expiration]

Comment: A little explanation would be nice, what does the code actually do and what does "1000*360000" mean here?

Comment: While testing in localhost Firefox rejected the expire date because SameSite is not set and thus defaults to none. Setting document.cookie = `${YOUR_COOKIE_OR_WHATEVER};${THE_EXPIRE_TIME_OR_WHATEVER};SameSite=lax` seams to resolve the issue.

Comment: Wow, Windows XP

Answer (score 75):

Below are code snippets to create and delete a cookie. The cookie is set for 1 day.

```js
// 1 Day = 24 Hrs = 24*60*60 = 86400.
```

1. By using max-age:

   - **Creating the cookie**:

   ```js
   document.cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue; max-age=86400; path=/;";
   ```

   - **Deleting the cookie**:

   ```js
   document.cookie = "cookieName=; max-age=- (any digit); path=/;";
   ```
2. By using expires:

   - **Syntax for creating the cookie for one day**:

   ```js
   var expires = (new Date(Date.now()+ 86400*1000)).toUTCString();
   document.cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue; expires=" + expires + ";path=/;"
   ```

Comment: `new Date(Date.now() + 86400)` is what I was looking for, but I wasn't sure if the Date format would be accepted, thanks.

Comment: In the expires usage example, I don't get the `expires + 86400` from the second line. You already added up the day (in ms) to line 1, right? What's the purpose of that additional `86400`?

Comment: Just what I wanted - thanks mate!

Comment: I've removed the erroneous addition @GustavoStraube

Answer (score 30):

Here's a function I wrote another application. Feel free to reuse:

```
function writeCookie (key, value, days) {
    var date = new Date();

    // Default at 365 days.
    days = days || 365;

    // Get unix milliseconds at current time plus number of days
    date.setTime(+ date + (days * 86400000)); //24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

    window.document.cookie = key + "=" + value + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString() + "; path=/";

    return value;
};
```

Comment: What does `+ date + (days * 86400000)` do?

Comment: `+` before a variable just returns the numerical value of an object. In this case, `+date` is equivalent to `d.valueOf()`, which also happens to be the value returned by `date.getTime()`.

Answer (score 18):

```js
document.cookie = "cookie_name=cookie_value; max-age=31536000; path=/";
```

Will set the value for a year.

Answer (score 5):

I use a function to store cookies with a custom expire time in days:

```
// use it like: writeCookie("mycookie", "1", 30)
// this will set a cookie for 30 days since now
function writeCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use like this ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)):

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{

var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie = c_name+"="+c_value+"; path=/";
}
```

Comment: Added the source, in the future, please ensure that you attribute copied code to the original source.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to second Polin's answer and just add one thing in case you are still stuck. This code certainly does work to set a specific cookie expiration time. One issue you may be having is that if you are using Chrome and accessing your page via "http://localhost..." or "file://", Chrome will not store cookies. The easy fix for this is to use a simple http server (like node's http-server if you haven't already) and navigate to your page explicitly as "http://127.0.0.1" in which case Chrome WILL store cookies for local development. This had me hung up for a bit as, if you don't do this, your expires key will simply have the value of "session" when you investigate it in the console or in Dev Tools.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser may be configured to accept only session cookies; if this is your case, any expiry time is transformed into session by your browser, you can change this setting of your browser or try another browser without such a configuration

Answer (score 0):

Remember that some browsers as Safari, will not allow you to set a cookie expiration bigger than 1 week. This is due to Safari's ITP: https://webkit.org/blog/9521/intelligent-tracking-prevention-2-3/

Basically, this will block the expiration time if you create/modify a cookie through ***document.cookie*** property. Only cookies created/modified on the server side will be able to have a bigger expiration time.

Other browsers could do the same thing in incognito mode, even with a shorter expiration time, only for the session.