# Saving user cookie Not working

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I want to save a cookie for a visitor. I use the code below but it seems it won't work for me. Please guide me where I am wrong

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['visited_alreadyxxx']))
    {
        setcookie('visited_alreadyxxx' , 'true' , time()+60*60*24*7*365);  
        alert("hi");
    }
</script>
```

[demo](http://8xxxd.com/session.php)

Edit : sorry for above code , does below code work correctly ?

```
<?php 
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['visited_alreadyxxx']))
        {
            setcookie('visited_alreadyxxx' , 'true' , time()+60*60*24*7*365);  
          ?>

<script>alert("hi");</script>
<?
        }

?>
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing PHP and JavaScript. You just cannot do that. The JavaScript engine will try to call `isset` and create a runtime error because, I assume, `isset` is not defined.

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing as Felix King. `isset` and `$_COOKIE` are PHP things.

Comment: oh sorry about that i am new to coding stuffs .Cant we set cookie without php ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie

Comment: Of course you can: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html.

Comment: hey my php code is working fine. how to change this time time()+60*60*24*7*365 to 1 hour ?

Comment: @Vishnu: `time()` returns the current time in seconds. If you want the cookie to expire in one our, you have to add one hour to the current tim. One hour are 3600 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can access cookies like that. It appears to be PHP, mixed with Javascript.

1. isset() is a PHP function
2. $_COOKIE is how you access cookies in PHP
3. setcookie is also PHP
4. alert is Javascript.

The Javascript interpreter doesn't know how to parse PHP, and will fail to execute.

Comment: oh sorry about that i am new to coding stuffs .Cant we set cookie without php ?

Comment: Yes see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154552/javascript-set-cookie-with-expire-time

Comment: hey my php code was working fine. how to change this time time()+60*60*24*7*365 to 1 hour ?