# How to set cookie's expire date with js?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

This is my script.

```js
<script>
        function save() {
            var x=document.getElementById("user").value;
            var y=document.getElementById("password").value;
            document.cookie=x+" "+y;
        }
        function write() {
            document.write(document.cookie);
        }
</script>
```

This works fine, it remembers the value of var x and y and writes them when function write() is called. When I close the browser the cookie gets deleted, as it should. But I would like to set an expire date of one year; I tried in many ways but I really can't get it to work. Any help?

Comment: Look at [this question at SO][1], it should help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154552/javascript-set-cookie-with-expire-time

Answer (score 6):

Add a max-age segment:

```
 ;max-age=<max-age-in-seconds>
```

[Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

This would expire your cookie in a day:

```
    function save() {
        var x=document.getElementById("user").value;
        var y=document.getElementById("password").value;
        document.cookie=x+"="+y+";max-age="+(3600*24);
    }
```

I recommend using a library for setting cookies, because there are a lot of gotchas when setting/reading cookies cross-browser. [For example the js-cookie library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

*Note: it's bad practice to store a plaintext password in a cookie. You're probably looking for a session cookie.*

Answer (score 1):

This is an example from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

```
document.cookie="cookiename=cookievalue; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write

```
document.cookie = "cookiename=value; expires= 03 Dec 2015 00:00"
```

However, if you just type "javascript cookies" on Google you can find this page: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
it's very useful.