# how to convert UTC date more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert to date to UTC due to cookie set expires date.

```
const date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // 1days add
$.cookie('AA', '', {
      expires: new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 
      date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds())),
    });
```

This code works well..
But, I want to know efficient and compact code!
Pleae tell me the other opinions!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `date.getUTCDate()` to get the UTC date instance. See [this documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getutcdate.asp).

So your code will be like:

```
const date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // 1days add
$.cookie('AA', '', {
   expires: date.toUTCString(),
});
```

Comment: getUTCDate returns date. I wan to get total dates. for example Thu Oct 24 2019 08:59:59 GMT+0900 (한국 표준시)

Comment: Then you can use, `date.toUTCString()`

Comment: I want to get date object. not string

Comment: In that case, you don't have to worry that much. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154552/javascript-set-cookie-with-expire-time. Using the `toUTCString()` will work. I will update the answer accordingly