# Add a value to a cookie with expiration data?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I add a cookie which expires in 2 months to 'test@gmail.com' from the following code

```
<div id="home">
    <div class="name" my-data="123">Email: test@gmail.com</div> 
</div>
```

---

I think the code for the actual time should be as follows but I do not know how to add the value to it:

```
function myemail () {
    var expiryDate = new Date();
  expiryDate.setMonth(expiryDate.getMonth() + 2);
    document.cookie = cookieName + '=y; expires=' + expiryDate.toGMTString
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript set cookie with expire time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154552/javascript-set-cookie-with-expire-time)

Comment: no because I still do not understand how to add the cookie to html part of the code 'test@gmail.com'

Comment: What do you mean by 'html part' ? Cookies can be managed by JS

Comment: This is what I need to do : Write a JavaScript code snippet that sets a cookie called 'myemail' with the value 'test@gmail.com' with a 2 months expiration.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have privileges to add an ID to your div, the following code works fine

```
<body>

    <div id="home">
        <div class="name" my-data="123" id="email-div">Email: test@gmail.com</div>
        <button onclick="myemail()">Set it</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        function myemail() {
            var expiryDate = new Date();
            var email = document.getElementById("email-div").textContent.split("Email:")[1]
            expiryDate.setMonth(expiryDate.getMonth() + 2);
            document.cookie = 'emailCookie=' + email + ';expires=' + expiryDate.toGMTString() + ';path=/';
        }
    </script>

</body
```

Well I have used a button to trigger the action. You can do the same in any event.

Comment: Can it be done without adding a new id?

Comment: You can use document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0] instead of ID, but only if you are sure, the class name is not used else where. Or XPath, if you are sure about the tag position, and it will not change

Comment: I hope you are not trying for XSS :D

Answer (score 0):

toGMTString is a function, you need to call.
Replace expiryDate.toGMTString to expiryDate.toGMTString()

```
const Cookie = {
get: function (name) {
    const nameEq = name + "=";
    const ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        let c = ca[i];

        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        }

        if (c.indexOf(nameEq) == 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEq.length, c.length);
        }
    }

    return null;
},

set: function (name, value, hours) {
    const expires = "";
    if (hours) {
        let date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (hours * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        const expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }

    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
};
```

You can change `hours` to whatever and of course
this one `date.setTime(date.getTime() + (hours * 60 * 60 * 1000));` to the corresponding formula

Usage`

Set: `Cookie.set('myemail', 'test@gmail.com', 1460) // 1460 is 2 months in hours`

Get: `Cookie.get('myemail')`

`const email = document.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].textContent.split(' ')[1]; Cookie.set('myemail', email, 1460);`

Comment: This is what I need to do : Write a JavaScript code snippet that sets a cookie called 'myemail' with the value 'test@gmail.com' with a 2 months expiration. –

Comment: So I edited my Answer. Hope this is what you need