# Set Cookie with jQuery expiry time not working what i put in

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm setting a cookie with jQuery, put in a lot of days. But it always expires after just 2 hours. What can be the problem? This script is working on another site.

```
 $('button.close').click(function(){
     hcontent();
    setCookie( 'popupCookie', 'closed', 99999 );
  });
  
  $('button.submit').click(function(){
    $('.popup-overlay').fadeOut();
     $('#id').hide();
    setCookie( 'popupCookie', 'submited', 99999 );
  });

  function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set a cookie with expire time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154552/how-can-i-set-a-cookie-with-expire-time)

Comment: Maybe the browser thinks that the date you are providing, is a bit much in the future ...? The year you're in there is 2297 after all.

Answer (score 0):

Went with the standard line and removed the above function. This one is working on every site. Not sure where the difference is.

```
document.cookie = "popupCookie=submited; max-age=31536000; path=/";
```