# Javascript set cookie expire time on button click

Tags: javascript

```
onClick="javascript:document.cookie='n=1'"
```

Im new in javascript

I have a btn click will set cookie, how can I set expire time 1 hour on this cookie?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154552/javascript-set-cookie-with-expire-time

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794989/how-to-set-a-cookie-to-expire-in-1-hour-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
onClick="setupCookie();"

function setupCookie() {
    document.cookie = "n=1";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.cookie = "n=0";
    }, 3600000); // 1 hour
}
```

Comment: This would be dependent on the user staying on the site for an hour.  If they navigate away from the page, the cookie's value will never be reset.

Answer (score 3):

When you write the cookie to the browser, you need to specify an expiration date or a max age.  However, note that max-age is ignored by Interent Explorer 8 and below. So if you're expecting to get usage from that browser, you can just rely on expires.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setMyCookie() {
   var now = new Date();
   var expires = new Date(now.setTime(now.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000)); //Expire in one hour
   document.cookie = 'n=1;path=/;expires='+expires.toGMTString()+';';
}
</script>
```

And your button can call this function like so:

```
<input type="button" onclick="setMyCookie();">Set Cookie</input>
```

Note that I've also included the path to indicate that this cookie is site-wide.

You can read more about expiring cookies with the date or max-age here:
http://mrcoles.com/blog/cookies-max-age-vs-expires/

Comment: This should probably be 
   now.setTime(now.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000); //Expire in one hour
   document.cookie = 'n=1;path=/;expires='+now.toGMTString()+';';
}
The value in expires is an integer; you want the updated Date in now

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I've updated the script to create a new Date object from now.setTime().

Answer (score 0):

On click you can call some javascript function and while creating cookie itself you can set expire time please refer this

[javascript set cookie with expire time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154552/javascript-set-cookie-with-expire-time)