# How to hide div for set period after clicking on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

i have a div that shows on page load that div also have a close button. what i want to do is to never show that div for 7 days when user click on close button. i know this functionality can be achieved using jquery or php cookies but i have no idea how to do this even after getting some info about cookies like here

[Javascript set cookie expire time on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638265/javascript-set-cookie-expire-time-on-button-click)

**Code**

```
<div id="content"><button id="close" onclick="setMyCookie();">Close</button></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set cookie for seven days like :

```
var now = new Date();
var days = 7;
var exp = new Date(now.getDate() + days);
document.cookie = 'MyCookie=1; expires='+exp.toUTCString();
```

And can check if cookie expired or not.

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');
if (document.cookie && document.cookie.indexOf('MyCookie=1') != -1){
    content.style.display = 'none';
}
else{
    content.style.display = 'block';
}
```