# I try to save in cookie for a period of 1 hour but I get invalid date

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a token and I want to save it in cookie for only 1 hour.

Here is my code :

```
        time= 3600 * 1000;
    let expires = new Date();
    expires.setDate(expires + time);
    console.log(expires);
    document.cookie =`${name}=${value};expires=${expires.toUTCString()};path=/`;
```

When I run it in chrome I see the following:

```
Invalid Date
```

For more info I use the following for implementing my function:

[How to set a cookie to expire in 1 hour in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794989/how-to-set-a-cookie-to-expire-in-1-hour-in-javascript)

Can anyone shed light on this? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't get the time on the `expires` before adding the hour to the time. Then you need to reset the time for `expires`...you skipped a few steps

Comment: @scrappedcola thanks let me give it a try and I will let you know about the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the `expires+time` part. You can't add a date to a number like that.
You could try something like

```
let expires=new Date(new Date().valueOf()+time);
```